# Can you import a non-archive project directory in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, project

I read [this](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/) article which shows how to import/export projects in Eclipse (although it seems a little outdated and I'm using 3.7 Indigo).

To export a project, you go to `File >> Export` and it creates some kind of "project archive" file on the local file system. You could then email it to someone else, who could then import the archive as a new project or into an existing project.

But what if you don't have an "archive" file to begin with?!? What if you just have the project files and directories but without all the Eclipse-metatdata (.project file, etc.)? Is there anyway to tell Eclipse to look at, say:

```
/home/myuser/some/path/to/project/root/
    src/main/java
        SomeObject.java
    build.xml
```

...and get it to read that as a new Java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the steps below:

1. Create a Java Project in `Eclipse` as below:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Load the project contents from your file system as below:

   [image]

   [image]

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`.project` and `.classpath` files are the base of the project structure. Without a `.project` file Eclipse won't recognize your project. The `.classpath` is important too but that one changes between environments. Should you use the files from another environment you'll have to reconfigure some settings.

Rather than emailing code, I suggest you use a Version Control system and, also, some Eclipse plugins. SVN + Subclipse for example.

If you trully want to send the project to another person just send him the project's folder and import it as an existing project by doing right click on the project explorer and selecting *Import > Existing Project into workspace*.